# What is the C# equivalent to std::vector::iterators?

Tags: c#, c++, vector, iterator

The following code snippet shows an `iterator` from the `std::vector` C++ lib. What is the C# equivalent to this? Can I simply loop through each item in the vector considering its not a linked list? What exactly is the iterator doing here and how can I do the equivalent in C#? The full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/QAADyUAe).

```
 std::vector<KMeanCluster>::iterator closest_cluster = clusters.begin();

    // Figure out which cluster this color is closest to in RGB space.
    for (std::vector<KMeanCluster>::iterator cluster = clusters.begin();
        cluster != clusters.end(); ++cluster) {
      uint distance_sqr = cluster->GetDistanceSqr(r, g, b);

      if (distance_sqr < distance_sqr_to_closest_cluster) {
        distance_sqr_to_closest_cluster = distance_sqr;
        closest_cluster = cluster;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ standard library iterators are defined in a way to resemble pointers that walk through a collection. In C# every collection that implements `IEnumerable` can be iterated in a `foreach` loop. Apart from that you can still do something similar to C++ iterators in C# using `Enumerator`s (which makes things harder in most cases):

```
IEnumerable<int> myCollection = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var enumerator = myCollection.GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
```

Actually the above is how a `foreach` loop iterates through a collection under the hood.

```
foreach(int num in myCollection)
    Console.WriteLine(num);
```

So in terms of your code this is the exact (but hard to code and understand) equivalent:

```
IEnumerator<KMeanCluster> closest_cluster = clusters.GetEnumerator();
while (closest_cluster.MoveNext())
{
    uint distance_sqr = closest_cluster.Current.GetDistanceSqr(r, g, b);
    if (distance_sqr < distance_sqr_to_closest_cluster)
    {
        distance_sqr_to_closest_cluster = distance_sqr;
        closest_cluster = cluster;
    }
}
```

and this is the easiest equivalent:

```
foreach(KMeanCluster closest_cluster in clusters)
{
    uint distance_sqr = closest_cluster.GetDistanceSqr(r, g, b);
    if (distance_sqr < distance_sqr_to_closest_cluster)
    {
        distance_sqr_to_closest_cluster = distance_sqr;
        closest_cluster = cluster;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An iterator is basically an object that allows serial, non-random access to a container.
Anyhow: You can use a normal loop in C#. A foreach loop is a bit closer to the C++ original syntaxwise

Answer (score 2):

In C# this might look like:

```
var closest_cluster = clusters.FirstOrDefault();
foreach (var cluster in clusters)
{
    uint distance_sqr = cluster.GetDistanceSqr(r, g, b);
    if (distance_sqr < distance_sqr_to_closest_cluster)
    {
        distance_sqr_to_closest_cluster = distance_sqr;
        closest_cluster = cluster;
    }
}
```

What `foreach` operator does is it's uses `IEnumerator` underneath and this is equivalent to your iterator.

Comment: This throws an exception if `clusters` does not contain any elements, unlike the C++ code. `FirstOrDefault()` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Of course, you might still need a null check before you try and use `closest_cluster`

Comment: @JohnL, yep but the code that uses the `closest_cluster` is outside of the current scope. Also there is no such a check in the original code: http://screencast.com/t/C7kzJXwwsVi8

Comment: Yes but then I would have thought the empty list case (or null list case, for that matter) were also outside the scope.

Comment: @JohnL, I agree. In case of `FirstOrDefault` it was more a matter of good coding style and that case shouldn't occur.

Answer (score 2):

Generic collection - [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78dfe2yb.aspx)

> Supports a simple iteration over a generic collection.

Non-generic collection - [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx)

> Supports a simple iteration over a nongeneric collection.

Those are interfaces and should be inherited and override. Methods such as `MoveNext` and `Reset`. Then you can use that class in loops.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [`iterator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) construct in C# but in this case you don't need to access it directly, instead using a [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) loop.  The code might look something like this.

```
Cluster closestCluster = clusters.firstOrDefault();

foreach (Cluster currentCluster in clusters)
{
   //Distance logic
   if (distanceSqr < distanceSqrToClosestCluster)
   {
        closestCluster = currentCluster;
   }
}
```

Internally the `foreach` accesses the iterator through the [`IEnumerable<Cluster>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface